# How to create item in to show in sales and purchase in quickbooks API PHP

Tags: php, api, quickbooks

I am using Quickbooks V3 by following this package. https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

I am creating item like this

```
$ItemService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Item();
$Item = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Item();
$Item->setName('My Item');
$Item->setType('Inventory');
$Item->setIncomeAccountRef('121');

if ($resp = $ItemService->add($this->context, $this->realm, $Item)) { 
    print('Our new Item ID is: [' . $resp . ']');
} else {
    print($ItemService->lastError($this->context));
}
```

It is showing item in sales only, but not enabled in purchase. How to create item to available in all categories?

Answer (score 0):

Did you refer to the documentation?

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/Item

Items for purchase have to have their purchased-related fields defined. You've only defined their sales-related fields:

> $Item->setIncomeAccountRef('121');

You should also be specifying:

- ExpenseAccountRef
- PurchaseDesc
- PurchaseCost
- AssetAccountRef

Comment: I have added this code while creating item. It is just adding in sales but not in purchase.
$Item->setName('My Item111');
$Item->setType('Inventory');
$Item->setIncomeAccountRef('121');
$Item->setPurchaseCost(0);
$Item->setAssetAccountRef('121');

Comment: Please make sure you are specifying ALL of the fields I have indicated above.